# React date picker filtering dates issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using https://reactdatepicker.com

I seem to be having an issue in **restricting weekends** as shown in the example.

I'm using class component and trying to implement this functional **example** from the [docs](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-filter-dates):

**Example from docs:**

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const isWeekday = date => {
    const day = getDay(date);
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  };
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      filterDate={isWeekday}
      placeholderText="Select a weekday"
    />
  );
};
```

**Here is what I tried:** I created the `isWeekday` function and passed it to the `DatePicker`.

```
import React from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import getDay from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'

const isWeekday = (date) => {
  const day = getDay(date)
  return day !== 0 && day !== 6
}

export class Random extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      settlementDate: new Date(),
    }
  }

  render() {
    <DatePicker
      selected={this.state.settlementDate}
      onChange={(date) => this.setState({ settlementDate: date })}
      minDate={new Date()}
      filterDate={isWeekday}
    />
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

How can I make a datepicker with weekends restricted?

Comment: Do you have more details on that traceback? I think something is missing here.

Comment: can you post the full component code ?

Comment: Cannot call a class as a function means that a function you are calling isn't actually a function. I would look at the stack trace and see what is trying to be called as a function. I have ran across this when I imported things incorrectly.

Comment: I've updated the post above. Still an issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

because you are **calling class as a function** after importing default member from `react-datepicker`:

**Incorrect:**

```
import getDay from 'react-datepicker' // You imported default class as `getDay`
const day = getDay(date) // You tried to call the class
```

**Note:** [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) isn't supposed to come from `react-datepicker`. It is a standard JS [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)'s method.

**Correct:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'

class SelectWeekDay extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      startDate: null,
    }
  }

  isWeekday = (date: Date) => {
    const day = date.getDay()
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={(date) =>
            this.setState({
              startDate: date,
            })
          }
          filterDate={this.isWeekday}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for `(date: Date)`

Comment: @FiddleFreak Can you post the full error message?

Comment: `Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.`. If I change it to just `(date)`, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I think you are using javascript not the [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), so `(date)` is the right way to achieve the same.

Comment: ah okay, this question was tagged for javascript so I assumed so.

Answer (score 0):

install date-fns.

Then try:

import getDay from "date-fns/getDay"